# How to programatically set selected Panorama item header?

Tags: windows-phone-7

For example: I have a header that is called menu 1 and menu 2

How do I change the text in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add content to the Panorama statically (in the designer) you can access the headers like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

    <controls:Panorama Title="my application" x:Name="MyPanorama">
        <controls:Panorama.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="PanoramaBackground.png"/>
        </controls:Panorama.Background>

        <controls:PanoramaItem Header="first item">
```

Code:

```
var panoramaItem = MyPanorama.Items[0] as PanoramaItem;
if (panoramaItem != null)
{
    panoramaItem.Header = "New Title";
}
```

Or, if you want the current PanoramaItem to change its Header:

```
var panoramaItem = MyPanorama.SelectedItem as PanoramaItem;
if (panoramaItem != null)
{
    panoramaItem.Header = "New Title";
}
```

Or, when you assign the PanoramaItem a name like this:

```
<controls:Panorama Title="my application" x:Name="MyPanorama">
    <controls:Panorama.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="PanoramaBackground.png"/>
    </controls:Panorama.Background>

    <controls:PanoramaItem Header="first item" x:Name="FirstItem">
```

Then you could code:

```
FirstItem.Header = "New Title";
```

When you use DataBinding to create the PanoramaItems you can just change the property of the data object/ViewModel that is bound to the header and it will update automatically.